# Make emacs autocomplete cpp files over binary files

Tags: bash, emacs, autocomplete, tab-completion

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793207/prevent-vim-from-opening-binary-files-accidentally), except for emacs instead of vim. The issue is that I have a cpp file that I want to open and when I type f[TAB] it autocompletes to foo the binary file foo instead of foo.cpp. Is there a way to turn of autocomplete for files with certain (or no) extension? Or is there a way to prioritize certain extensions?

EDIT:
I've used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791099/preferring-certain-file-extensions-with-emacs-file-name-completion) for autocompletion in the minibuffer, but I want a solution for Bash autocompletion.

EDIT:
I've found that I can do `export FIGNORE=.bin` to ignore all files with the .bin extension in Bash autocomplete. The issue with this solution is that this doesn't work for a file with no extension, and also there's no way to make this occur only when there are no .cpp files in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you give it some extension (e.g. .bin) then you can ignore it with  completion-ignored-extensions:

> When completing file names, Emacs usually omits certain alternatives
>   that are considered unlikely to be chosen, as determined by the list
>   variable completion-ignored-extensions. Each element in the list
>   should be a string; any file name ending in such a string is ignored
>   as a completion alternative. Any element ending in a slash (/)
>   represents a subdirectory name. The standard value of
>   completion-ignored-extensions has several elements including ".o",
>   ".elc", and "~". For example, if a directory contains ‘foo.c’ and
>   ‘foo.elc’, ‘foo’ completes to ‘foo.c’. However, if all possible
>   completions end in “ignored” strings, they are not ignored: in the
>   previous example, ‘foo.e’ completes to ‘foo.elc’. Emacs disregards
>   completion-ignored-extensions when showing completion alternatives in
>   the completion list.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Options.html